# Is there a way to open all files that match a certain directory structure on windows DOS / Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ms-dos

I'm on a windows (server 2008) computer that serves websites. The sites are organised into folders:

```
c:/Websites/
           /www.mysite.com
           /www.mysite.co.uk
           /www.mysite.com.au
           /beta.mysite.com
           /beta.mysite.co.uk
           /www.mysite.com.au
```

Each of these folders shares almost identical content, apart from config files like web.config.

I want to open the same file within all these websites to perform some editing.

Is there a Dos / Powershell command I can write to open all files that share the same directory structure, file name and extension, for example opening the config files that are within a specific directories off of the root websites folder?

Can I open them into a specific text editor?

Comment: Your question is confusing. In the title you want to open all files based upon directory structure, yet your question reads as if it's only 1 type of file and you know where they are (so no need to open by structure)

Comment: Okay - I've clarified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this powershell script:

```
$editorPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
$websites = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:/Websites" | Where { $_.PSIsContainer }
foreach ($website in $websites)
{
    $webConfigPath = $website.FullName + "\web.config"
    if (Test-Path -Path $webConfigPath)
    {
        Start-Process -FilePath $editorPath -ArgumentList $webConfigPath
    }
}
```

It will open all `web.config` files in all the folders of `C:/Websites` with notepad++.

You could also use [AppCmd.exe](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) to get the websites. This will only get websites instead of all folders.

Comment: Hi digiguru, did this answer work for you?

Comment: I would just point out that your answer was a great springboard, but I think it was slower because it loops through directories and then tries to match a file inside. My answer only loops through the web.config files and seems to perform faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script I have used in it's entireity

```
#First choose an editor
$editorPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

#Next loop through a folder recusivly looking for "web.config"
#Recursive allows us to get websites stored inside websites
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:/Websites/" -recurse -filter web.config |

    #This is a where clause for each file.
    #I can find just the websites for a specific domain 
    #(or just delete this line below)
    ?{ $_.Directory.Name -match ".co.uk" } |

    #Now fire open that editor with this specific file
    %{Start-Process -FilePath $editorPath -ArgumentList $_.fullname}
```

The files fill drop into your editor one by one as they are found.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer was based upon the original question (Since question is updated, this answer is not 100% relevant but, it may still be useful in future so I won't delete it)*

You can use the start command in a batch file. Since I assume you already know where the config files are, you'll be able to write a list and then execute it from a batch file.

```
START c:/Websites/www.mysite.com/web.config  
START c:/Websites/www.mysite.co.uk/web.config  
START c:/Websites/www.mysite.au/web.config
```

You may need to associate the config file to open with a specific editor as this will open the file with the associated program.

Comment: Assuming that there may be more websites in the future, I don't want to change this BAT file every time there is a new site.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple *nix equivalent hints out to me that we should spend time in learning *nix shell commands and scripting, even if we predominantly work on MS Windows:

```
find . -name web.config | xargs start notepad++
```

This work on MS Windows only if you have Unix utilities installed, such as via [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or (my personal favourite) git bash, which is part of [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win).